# AzureADB2C NextJS 13

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-ad-b2c, next.js13

My oAuth for GitHub, and Google is working fine. Now I am trying to add Microsoft oAuth, and now I am spinning the wheel for 2 days. Would appreciate it if someone could help. I am using NextJs 13 and Next-Auth:^4.0.1. the code in [...nextAuth].ts is as follows:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import AzureADB2CProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c"

providers: [
   GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    AzureADB2CProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZUREADB2C_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZUREADB2C_SECRET,
      tenantId: process.env.AZUREADB2C_TENANT_ID,
      primaryUserFlow: "B2C_1_myflow",
      authorization: { params: { scope: "offline_access openid" } },
    }), 
  ], 
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  jwt: {
    // A secret to use for key generation (you should set this explicitly)
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin", // Displays signin buttons
    // signOut: '/auth/signout', // Displays form with sign out button
    error: '/auth/error', // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
  },
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl
    },
  },
  events: {},
  debug: true,
})
```

In the signin.tsx I have the following code:

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import {
  GithubLoginButton,
  GoogleLoginButton,
  MicrosoftLoginButton,
} from "react-social-login-buttons"

  const handleSignIn = async (provider) => {
    const response = await signIn(provider)
    console.log("response", response)
    if (response?.ok) {
      // Successful sign-in, now redirect based on the condition
     
    } else {
     console.log ('Error in signing', response?.error)


   return ( 
    <div>
         
                  <GoogleLoginButton
                    onClick={() => handleSignIn("google")}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <GithubLoginButton
                    onClick={() => handleSignIn("github")}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <MicrosoftLoginButton
                    onClick={() => handleSignIn("azureadb2c")}
                  />

                
          </div>
        )
```

The above code is working perfectly well, other than AzureADB2C. I did have a proper tenant created, and an application and its secret, etc in Azure, but when I click on the Azure button, nothing happens, no error, but the page flickers and I am back to the same page. The console log does flicker for a second saying undefined, but that message gets with Google and Github too but then I get prompted with Google and Github login. I am expecting to see a Microsoft login screen like all other login (google, Github) screens. What am I missing?

One last question, i see AzureADB2CProvider take TenantId but many blogs and YouTube show it is supposed to be Tenant Name. What is right? However, I tried my code by giving a Tenant_Id and Tenant Name too.